# Modifier "enabled" not working with Tailwind CSS v3

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I can't get the `enabled` modifier to work with Tailwind CSS v3.

From the Tailwind docs, it is described to work like [this](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#enabled).
On the Tailwind Play site, it [works as expected](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Ukm3R90eXU?size=540x720).

I can not get the same to work in my own application. If I add this to my code (the `bg-black-100` is a custom color defined in the theme file, also it is React):

```
<button className="bg-black-100 p-2 enabled:hover:bg-white">Hello</button>
```

Nothing happens on hover. If I remove the `enabled` modifier, hover works. The `enabled` modifier is [enabled by default](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#quick-reference).

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Tailwind config:

```
const theme = require('./src/components/lib/tailwind.theme');

module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: theme,
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
  ],
}
```

The theme file doesn't look very relevant, as I've done nothing there that has to do with modifiers.

Tailwind version: 3.0.24.

Comment: `enabled` is part of a regular class name and is something that tailwind terms "a modifier". It is not a psuedo-class.

Comment: @Quentin Updated the question. Also answered it, an update seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: `enabled` variant was introduced in 3.1.0 release, see [changelog](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#310---2022-06-08)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It only partially solved the issue. I still have it elsewhere.

I updated Tailwind to version 3.1.7, and it seems to have solved the issue. If anyone else has a similar problem with enabled, try to update Tailwind.